# Python: is there a more efficient way to repeatedly check for mouse?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm currently running Python 3.5 on Mac and I can't seem to find a way to be more efficient with my code.

In all I'm currently making a wheel of fortune game (or basically hangman), and I have it so that when the user clicks on a letter it checks if the letter is in the word etc.

Is there a better way than writing 26 if statements and checking coordinates each time? Is there a more efficient way of checking for coordinates using if statements?

```
while True:
    mouse = win.getMouse()
    if 35 < mouse.x < 65 and 85 < mouse.y < 115:
        ans = "a"
        break
    elif 65 < mouse.x < 95 and 85 < mouse.y < 115:
        ans = "b"
        break
    elif 95 < mouse.x < 125 and 85 < mouse.y < 115:
        ans = "c"
        break
    elif 125 < mouse.x < 155 and 85 < mouse.y < 115:
        ans = "d"
        break
    elif 155 < mouse.x < 185 and 85 < mouse.y < 115:
        ans = "e"
        break
    elif 185 < mouse.x < 215 and 85 < mouse.y < 115:
        ans = "f"
        break
    elif 215 < mouse.x < 245 and 85 < mouse.y < 115:
        ans = "g"
        break
    elif 245 < mouse.x < 275 and 85 < mouse.y < 115:
        ans = "h"
        break
    elif 275 < mouse.x < 305 and 85 < mouse.y < 115:
        ans = "i"
        break
    elif 305 < mouse.x < 335 and 85 < mouse.y < 115:
        ans = "j"
        break
    elif 35 < mouse.x < 65 and 115 < mouse.y < 145:
        ans = "k"
        break
    elif 65 < mouse.x < 95 and 115< mouse.y < 145:
        ans = "l"
        break
    elif 95 < mouse.x < 125 and 115 < mouse.y < 145:
        ans = "m"
        break
    elif 125 < mouse.x < 155 and 115 < mouse.y < 145:
        ans = "n"
        break
    elif 155 < mouse.x < 185 and 115 < mouse.y < 145:
        ans = "o"
        break
    elif 185 < mouse.x < 215 and 115 < mouse.y < 145:
        ans = "p"
        break
    elif 215 < mouse.x < 245 and 115 < mouse.y < 145:
        ans = "q"
        break
    elif 245 < mouse.x < 275 and 115 < mouse.y < 145:
        ans = "r"
        break
    elif 275 < mouse.x < 305 and 115 < mouse.y < 145:
        ans = "s"
        break
    elif 305 < mouse.x < 335 and 115 < mouse.y < 145:
        ans = "t"
        break
    elif 35 < mouse.x < 65 and 145 < mouse.y < 175:
        ans = "u"
        break
    elif 65 < mouse.x < 95 and 145 < mouse.y < 175:
        ans = "v"
        break
    elif 95 < mouse.x < 125 and 145 < mouse.y < 175:
        ans = "w"
        break
    elif 125 < mouse.x < 155 and 145 < mouse.y < 175:
        ans = "x"
        break
    elif 155 < mouse.x < 185 and 145 < mouse.y < 175:
        ans = "y"
        break
    elif 185 < mouse.x < 215 and 145 < mouse.y < 175:
        ans = "z"
        break
```

Comment: why is 35 followed by 305, not 335?

Comment: Probably next row, happens at 'k' too...

Answer (score 2):

As simple solution using a calculation vs. multiple if statements:

```
import string

while True:
    mouse = win.getMouse()
    x, xr = divmod(mouse.x-35, 30)
    y, yr = divmod(mouse.y-85, 30) 
    if not(0 <= x < 10 and 0 <= y < 3):   # Guard values
        continue
    if xr == 0 or yr == 0:                # Gridlines?
        continue
    try:
        ans = string.ascii_lowercase[10*y+x]
        break
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

e.g. mouse(x=102, y=143) would return 'm'

Comment: #1: The OP's code doesn't set ans if (e.g.) x = 65, which could be an oversight, I admit, but could equally well represent grid lines.  #2: Your code will set ans to `"h"` if x = 65 and y = 45..

Comment: Could add a simple guard `if (mouse.x-35)%30 == 0: continue` and similarly for `y` to skip the grid line.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to avoid the big if statement.

```
def check_pos(x, y):
    table = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    idx = (x - (35-30)) / 30
    idy = (y - (85-30)) / 30

    # each row has 10 cells
    offset = idx + (idy -1) * 10
    if 1 <= offset <= 26:
        return table[offset-1]
```

Comment: `map` is a python builtin - not a good name. Also the letters are spread over 3 rows, which is why `x` resets in the OPs question.

Comment: @AChampion Yeah, I made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
alpha=string.ascii_lowercase
mouse = win.getMouse()
for idx,i in enumerate(range(35,335,30)):
    if mouse.x>i and mouse.x<i+30:
        if mouse.y>85 and mouse.y<115:
            ans=alpha[idx]
            break
        elif mouse.y>115 and mouse.y<145:
            ans=alpha[idx + 10]
            break
        elif mouse.y>145 and mouse.y<175:
            ans=alpha[idx+20]
            break
```